# 'pip list' in virtual environment (venv) does not provide encapsulated packages

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

I have troubles with python's venv in Ubuntu 20.04, as `pip list` does not show the list of the encapsulated packages of the virtual environment.

I setup a virtual environment folder via

```
python -m venv dummyname
```

After activating the environment via `source dummyname/bin/activate`, `pip list` does not provide the list of package within the virtual environment but only the full list of packages which are installed in Ubuntu (I also have ROS noetic installed but that is just a side note). So, the list of packages look like:

```
[...]
rqt-srv                       0.4.9  
rqt-tf-tree                   0.6.3  
rqt-top                       0.4.10 
rqt-topic                     0.4.13 
rqt-web                       0.4.10 
rviz                          1.14.19
sensor-msgs                   1.13.1 
setuptools                    44.0.0 
smach                         2.5.0  
smach-ros                     2.5.0  
smclib                        1.8.6  
tf                            1.13.2 
tf-conversions                1.13.2 
tf2-geometry-msgs             0.7.6  
tf2-kdl                       0.7.6  
tf2-py                        0.7.6  
tf2-ros                       0.7.6  
topic-tools                   1.15.15
urdfdom-py                    0.4.6  
xacro                         1.14.14
[...]
```

I tried `./pip list` and `./python -m pip list` in the virtual environment bin folder but with the same result.

Does somebody have a solution?

Thanks!

On Windows 10, I did the same and the result was (which I am looking for)

```
(venv) >pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        19.2.3
setuptools 41.2.0
```

which are the packages of a freshly installed environment using venv. I expect the same result on Ubuntu.

Comment: What is `sys.path` inside the venv? Is `include-system-site-packages` set to true in `$VIRTUAL_ENV/pyvenv.cfg`? Did you add any directories to `PYTHONPATH` as part of your ros installation?

Comment: Try `path/to/dummyname/bin/python -m pip list`: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers! 

@sinroc: I tried `~/sources/test/test/venv/bin/python -m pip list` but I got the same result as listed above.

@Brain: Might be the case that ROS messed up python installation. But I installed ROS according to the manuals and I created a couple of catkin workspaces.

Comment: @Brain: 
`>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/home/user/tmp/upc_edu/workspaces/catkin_ws7/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/home/user/tmp/upc_edu/workspaces/catkin_ws6/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/home/user/tmp/upc_edu/workspaces/catkin_ws5/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/user/sources/test/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages']`

Comment: @Brain: pyvenv.cfg
`home = /home/user/sources/test/python_general/venv/bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.8.10`
(I changed the home path. I think originally it was set to /usr/bin)

Comment: @Brain: `$PYTHONPATH
bash: /home/user/tmp/upc_edu/workspaces/catkin_ws7/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages:/home/user/tmp/upc_edu/workspaces/catkin_ws6/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages:/home/user/tmp/upc_edu/workspaces/catkin_ws5/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages:/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages: File not found`